# Scope variables not loading on page load AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a chart on one of my views in my one page app using `angular-chart.js` http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/. The issue is that the chart won't load when the view initializes because the data hasn't yet loaded via the API in the factory. No matter how long I stay on that view, the data won't populate. However, if I go to a different view on the one page app, and come back, the data is there, since it has already loaded in the factory.

It's my understanding that once the data is loaded from factory, that the chart should update immediately because of data bindingl, but why won't it do this on the first view?

Factory (where the data is loaded via `service.getChartData()`)

```js
app.factory('chartFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

  var service = {
    height_chart: window.innerHeight * 0.4,
    labels: [],
    series: ['GDAX Value'],
    data: [],
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          id: 'y-axis-1',
          //    type: 'linear',
          display: true,
          position: 'left',
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: false,
            callback: function(value, index, values) {
              if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
              } else {
                return '$' + value;
              }
            }
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          display: false
        }]
      }
    },
    getChartData: function() {
      $http.get('/portfolio/get-chart-data')
        .then(function(response) {
          service.labels = response.data[0]
          service.data = response.data[1]
        })
    }
  }

  return service

}])
```

Controller

```js
app.controller('chartCtrl', chartCtrl)
chartCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$interval', 'chartFactory']

function chartCtrl($scope, $interval, chartFactory) {

  var vmChart = this
  
  vmChart.height_chart = chartFactory.height_chart
  vmChart.labels = chartFactory.labels
  vmChart.series = chartFactory.series
  //this data hasn't loaded yet. 
  vmChart.data = [chartFactory.data]
  vmChart.onClick = function(points, evt) {
    console.log(points, evt)
  }
  vmChart.datasetOverride = [{
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
  }]
  vmChart.options = chartFactory.options


  chartFactory.getChartData()
  //the chart never shows up on the first view, even after the function loads the data in the factory.

}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="chartCtrl as vmChart" class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="vmChart.data" chart-labels="vmChart.labels" chart-series="vmChart.series" chart-options="vmChart.options" chart-dataset-override="vmChart.datasetOverride" chart-click="vmChart.onClick" style="width:100%;">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Just to clarify - the chart does load, but not until I switch to a different view then back again. How do I get the chart to load on. the first view once the data is loaded in the factory?

Comment: try to put the `vmChart.data` inside the promise `chartFactory.getChartData().then(function(data){ vmChart.data = data;}`

Answer (score 0):

A http request takes around 200 ms to fetch data but the DOM gets loaded before the request is completed.So the first time when you land on the page ,the chart data gets populated but only after the whole page has been loaded.

Try this:
Make the getChartData function 'async' and add 'await' to http request to tell DOM to wait till the request has been completed.

In Chart Factory :

```
getChartData: async function() {
     await $http.get('/portfolio/get-chart-data')
        .then(function(response) {
          service.labels = response.data[0]
          service.data = response.data[1]
        })
    }
```

Comment: Likely the correct answer. Unfortunately no longer working on this project so can’t test it.

Answer (score -1):

Please add chartFactory.getChartData() after vm declaration, like below-

```
app.controller('chartCtrl', chartCtrl)
chartCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$interval', 'chartFactory']

function chartCtrl($scope, $interval, chartFactory) {

  var vmChart = this
  chartFactory.getChartData()

  vmChart.height_chart = chartFactory.height_chart
  vmChart.labels = chartFactory.labels
  vmChart.series = chartFactory.series
  //this data hasn't loaded yet. 
  vmChart.data = [chartFactory.data]
  vmChart.onClick = function(points, evt) {
    console.log(points, evt)
  }
  vmChart.datasetOverride = [{
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
  }]
  vmChart.options = chartFactory.options



  //the chart never shows up on the first view, even after the function loads the data in the factory.

}
```

Comment: this doesn't fix the issue, I think because the code is async

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You are right, you have to use chartFactory data in the success callback. Use the $q service in the chartFactory  and return the promise. Let me know if you need sample code.